# Create category rows from count of list items in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of job vacancy data in a pandas dataframe I have 'tagged' by the strings it contains.  E.g., if C# is mentioned in the title or description, `C#` is added to that row under the `languages` column.

I now want to summarise the count of each skill in the entire dataframe.  Original dataframe:

```
    languages                   frameworks     platforms    databases       other
0   [SQL, C]                    []             [AWS]        []              []
1   [SQL]                       []             []           [SQL Server]    []
2   [SQL, C#]                   [ASP.NET, ASP] []           [SQL Server]    []
3   [JavaScript, HTML, CSS,]    []             []           []              []
4   [JavaScript, Python, Java]  [React]        []           []              []
...
```

Desired:

```
    skill_category   skill        count
0   languages        SQL          3
1   languages        C            1
2   languages        C#           1
3   languages        JavaScript   2
...
9   frameworks       ASP.NET      1
10  frameworks       ASP          1
...
12  platforms        AWS          1
...
14  databases        SQL Server   2
...
15  other            Hadoop       1
etc.
```

I have tried:

- Outputting the relevant parts of the df into a python list of dictionaries and using for loops and counters to count the skills in each category.  I can then create a new dataframe from this, but this is a lot of code for something I feel should be possible with pandas.
- Looked in to pandas' `.pivot()` method, though I can't work out a way to have the column names (`languages`, `frameworks` etc.) become rows for each skill.
- Used pandas' `.explode()` and `.value_counts()` methods to count the skills in each column, e.g.:

```
In[12]:   df['languages'].explode().value_counts()
Out[12]:    
JavaScript     39
SQL            32
C#             28
HTML           24
Java           24
...
```

But this only works column-by-column.  I need a dataframe with a category row for creating [faceted visualisations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjW5KLJ6IHoAhUSVRUIHc6sAC0QFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplot.ly%2Fpython%2Ffacet-plots%2F&usg=AOvVaw0bnpKpV2SMYmcCqP8Wb5gu) in plotly.

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the answer! But stack all columns into one tall series before counting:

```
counts = df.stack().explode()\
           .reset_index().groupby(["level_1", 0]).count()
counts = counts.reset_index()
counts.columns = "skill_category", "skill", "count"
```